# How do you set the default store to a FixtureAdapter in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to bootstrap a small application with Ember 1.0.0-rc1. The application will be doing some stuff with images. I don't have any sort of backend to the application yet, so I'm trying to use FixtureAdapter on some JSON that I've embedded in the source of the web page.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to hook up the store properly. I keep getting an error about needing to set YourAppName.Store.

> Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your application does not have a
>   'Store' property defined. Attempts to call 'all' on model classes will
>   fail. Please provide one as with 'YourAppName.Store =
>   DS.Store.extend()'

But unless I've totally missed something, I did set it:

```
window.YIH = Ember.Application.create();

YIH.Photo = DS.Model.extend({
  url: DS.attr('string'),
});
YIH.Photo.FIXTURES = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('images').innerHTML);
YIH.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter
});

YIH.photoController = Em.ArrayController.create({
  content: YIH.Photo.all(), // blows up
})
```

I've hacked around trying to make this work setting other properties, but to no avail.

Comment: http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/using-fixtures/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: the fiddle now uses Ember RC2 with Ember-Data rev 12

You don't need to `create` the controller, simply append the controller class and `extend` from either `Ember.ArrayController` for collections or `Ember.ObjectController` for a single object.

```
YIH.PhotosController = Em.ArrayController.extend();
YIH.PhotosPhotoController = Em.ObjectController.extend();
```

Ember will instantiate these controllers and manage them throughout your application lifetime.

To setup the store with the `FixtureAdapter`, do this:

```
YIH.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});
```

To setup the `content` of your controller, it's recommended to do it through routing, like the following:

```
YIH.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('photos', function() {
        this.route('photo', { path: ':photo_id' });
    });
});

YIH.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('photos');
    }
});

YIH.PhotosRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return YIH.Photo.find();
    }
});

YIH.PhotosPhotoRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return YIH.Photo.find(params.photo_id);
    }
});
```

The controllers will receive the `model` through `setupController` which is baked into the `Route` even if you don't write it. It looks like this:

```
SomeRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('content', model);
    }
});
```

and you can modify it if you want.

I'm not sure whether your JSON format is correct since you didn't add in your code. Either way, each JSON object should have an `id` property and your model should **not** have an `id` property, unless you configure your store/adapter to have a primary key different than `id`. Throughout the application, sometimes you'll be calling the id directly, but sometimes you'll have to use naming conventions (e.g.: dynamic segment in the "photo" route).

For a model like this:

```
YIH.Photo = DS.Model.extend({
    url: DS.attr('string'),
    caption: DS.attr('string')
});
```

In order to add fixtures, you'll have to provide JSON like this:

```
YIH.Photo.FIXTURES = [
    { id: 1,
      url: 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/516cyMC9O7L.jpg',
      caption: 'Image 1'
    },
    { id: 2,
      url: 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51og8BkN8jL._SS250_.jpg',
      caption: 'Image 2'
    }
];
```

You might want to check this sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/n3hY6/